# Depletion type MOSFET for dump load resistors in wind turbines

Tags: mosfet, switching, windturbine

I recently asked a question to do with dump load resistors for wind turbines see link:
[MOSFET Driving for a Dump Load Resistor within a wind turbine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/704564/mosfet-driving-for-a-dump-load-resistor-within-a-wind-turbine/704956#704956)
General Specs:
6kW Wind turbine
Dump load: 500 V
Dump load Resistor :42 Ohms
See circuitry and other link for more info:
[image: switching circuit]
[image: Full circuit]

The dump will have two main functions the first is to manage overvoltage and divert the load when over 500V is seen.
There is now a secondary function that in the event of a grid outtage (and the MOSFETs can't be powered) the load will default to the dump load resistor and take all of the load protecting the inverter. Given this secondary function I am starting to lean towards the use of a depletion type MOSFET although I know this is not common within industry. Furthermore, this would also mean that the MOSFETs would have to be specced to handle higher voltages. I'm also unsure how a MOSFET driver works with a depletion type MOSFET?

I am not keen on powering the MOSFETs from the wild AC as this would add a lot more complexity.
Can i also just put a circuit breaker further up the system to protect the rectifier?

Any advice on how on earth I go about this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "...in the event of a power output (and the MOSFETs can't be powered) the load..." What is the "power output" event that you are talking about in this context?

Comment: If you have 500V at considerable current available, how is gate voltage not also available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest investigating using a simple relay with an N.C. contact.

In any case if there is no voltage available to work with (which itself could be used to control a MOSFET or whatever) then the load resistor is not going to do anything. Maybe you need a circuit that uses that as a supply and your control signal turns it off.

If you insist on using depletion MOSFETs, the lowest value I see for an adequately rated for breakdown voltage and available part for Rds(on) with 0V is 1.5Ω (more than double that when hot!), so it's not a very good switch and your 12A current will be too high for a single part to handle. It's not a ridiculous approach but it would require some means of sharing current between a number of devices with the available parts I can see. The parts would also be single-sourced which may be a concern for non-technical reasons.

You drive an N-channel depletion mode MOSFET off by giving it a negative gate voltage wrt source. That's not hard to do if you have a power source. A charge pump or DC-DC module can generate the negative voltage.

Comment: The only thing is we would really love to do PWM with this circuit and obviously with a relay that is not possible. My thought at the moment is just to have a circuit breaker further up the circuit and use an enahancement n-type MOSFET in tthe event there is a power outage?